# Python: Return statement inside if condition returns only last value

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, return

I have a `fruits` dataframe with columns: `(Name, Color, ID)` and a `sentence` dataframe with columns: `(Sentence, ID)`. I need to compare each record of the fruits dataframe with the sentence dataframe and if the fruit name appears exactly as such in the sentence, concatenate its color before the fruit name in the sentence.

This is what I have done:

```
import pandas as pd
import regex as re

# create fruit dataframe 
fruit_data = [['Apple', 'Red', 1], ['Mango', 'Yellow', 2], ['Grapes', 'Green', 3]] 
fruit_df = pd.DataFrame(fruit_data, columns = ['Name', 'Color', 'ID']) 
print(fruit_df)

# create sentence dataframe 
sentence = [['I like Apple', 1], ['I like ripe Mango', 2], ['Grapes are juicy', 3]] 
sentence_df = pd.DataFrame(sentence, columns = ['Sentence', 'ID']) 
print(sentence_df)


def search(desc, name, color, id):
    flag = 0
    if re.findall(r"\b" + name + r"\b", desc):
        desc_id = (sentence_df[sentence_df['Sentence'] == desc]['ID'].values[0])
        if desc_id == id:
            flag = 1
        
        if flag == 1:
            # for loop is used because fruit can appear more than once in sentence
            all_indexes = []
            for match in re.finditer(r"\b" + name + r"\b", desc):
                     all_indexes.append(match.start())
            
            arr = list(desc)
            for idx in sorted(all_indexes, reverse=True):
                       arr.insert(idx, color + " ")

            new_desc = ''.join(arr)
           
            print("modified sentence: ", new_desc)
            return new_desc 

def compare(name, color, id):
    sentence_df['Result'] = sentence_df['Sentence'].apply(lambda x: search(x, name, color, id))
    

fruit_df.apply(lambda x: compare(x['Name'], x['Color'], x['ID']), axis=1)
print ("The final result is: ")
print(sentence_df['Result'])
```

The result of the code is:

```
     Name    Color  ID
0   Apple     Red    1
1   Mango  Yellow    2
2  Grapes   Green    3

            Sentence  ID
0       I like Apple   1
1  I like ripe Mango   2
2   Grapes are juicy   3


modified sentence:  I like Red Apple
modified sentence:  I like ripe Yellow Mango
modified sentence:  Green Grapes are juicy


The final result is: 
0                      None
1                      None
2    Green Grapes are juicy
Name: Result, dtype: object
```

The sentences are getting modified correctly but the problem is, the first two sentences are not getting stored inside the `Result` column of the sentence dataframe, only the last sentence is being stored. Is this the right way to do it or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

After some modifications:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
# create fruit dataframe 
fruit_data = [['Apple', 'Red', 1], ['Mango', 'Yellow', 2], ['Grapes', 'Green', 3]] 
fruit_df = pd.DataFrame(fruit_data, columns = ['Name', 'Color', 'ID']) 
print(fruit_df)

# create sentence dataframe 
sentence = [['I like Apple', 1], ['I like ripe Mango', 2], ['Grapes are juicy', 3]] 
sentence_df = pd.DataFrame(sentence, columns = ['Sentence', 'ID']) 
print(sentence_df)


def search(ids):
    name = fruit_df[fruit_df['ID']==ids]['Name'].values[0]
    desc = sentence_df[sentence_df['ID']==ids]['Sentence'].values[0]
    color = fruit_df[fruit_df['ID']==ids]['Color'].values[0]
    if True:# kept to maintain this indentation
            # for loop is used because fruit can appear more than once in sentence
            all_indexes = []
            for match in re.finditer(r"\b" + name + r"\b", desc):
                     all_indexes.append(match.start())
            
            arr = list(desc)
            for idx in sorted(all_indexes, reverse=True):
                       arr.insert(idx, color + " ")

            new_desc = ''.join(arr)
           
            print("modified sentence: ", new_desc)
            return new_desc


sentence_df['Result'] = sentence_df['ID'].apply(lambda x: search(x))
    

print("The final result is: ")
print(sentence_df['Result'])
```

---

Changes:

The main problem was here `fruit_df.apply`. This called the compare function for every item in `fruits_df`, which means in the example provided 3 times.

Then `compare` modified the all entries in Result column based on the current fruit passed by `fruit_df.apply`.

So, first step would be to make it just one call.

Another change needed was to use the `foreign-key : ID` for what it is.

ID is present in both the dataframes, so its enough to identify the `name`,`desc` and `color` in `search` function.

---

Output:

```
      Name   Color  ID
0   Apple     Red   1
1   Mango  Yellow   2
2  Grapes   Green   3


            Sentence  ID
0       I like Apple   1
1  I like ripe Mango   2
2   Grapes are juicy   3


modified sentence:  I like Red Apple
modified sentence:  I like ripe Yellow Mango
modified sentence:  Green Grapes are juicy


The final result is: 
0            I like Red Apple
1    I like ripe Yellow Mango
2      Green Grapes are juicy
Name: Result, dtype: object
```

**Edit** : On demand by OP, a *quick fix* version for the solution.

Just change the bottom of your original code as follows,

```
def compare(name, color, id):
    sentence_df['Result'] = sentence_df['Result'].apply(lambda x: search(x, name, color, id) or x)
    
sentence_df['Result'] = sentence_df['Sentence']

fruit_df.apply(lambda x: compare(x['Name'], x['Color'], x['ID']), axis=1)
print ("The final result is: ")
print(sentence_df['Result'])
```

Note: In this *fix*, the problems mentioned above have not been technically tackled with. Just that a small bypass was introduced to reach the desired output.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it works great but I shouldn't refactor the code though.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the Dataframe.apply method in both places is the problem in your code.
The apply method helps you apply a method on any axis of your dataframe and not add a new column and assign a value to it.
If you were to be working on the same dataframe and wanted to do the above operation, you could have used .assign method. Which lets you assign a new column with its values being calculated from the other columns values.
For your code, if you wanted to keep the same code rather than refactor it as advised above ,what you need is just a loop.

```
for idx, row in fruit_df.iterrows():
result = search(sentence_df.loc[idx,"Sentence"], row["Name"], row["Color"], row["ID"])
sentence_df.loc[idx,"Result"] = result
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I heard that dataframe.apply() is more efficient than iterrows(), so that's why I wrote it using df.apply(). Is it possible to rectify the problem using df.apply() alone?

Comment: Since DataFrame.apply method either applies to columns or rows then the answer is "No".
Unless, you wanna add an empty "Result" Column from the get go and do your .apply method on the Result column series.